# SharedObject or XML for data storage in AS3 for game development for android devices

Tags: android, xml, actionscript-3, flash

i'm currently making an android game using flash only. i have variables User(string), Levels_unlocked(int), Money(int), and Highscore(int) that the user will save while the app is running.

how can i do this? thanks in advance for any replays! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the FileStream class in AIR to save locally on Android. [FileStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fla%20sh/filesystem/FileStream.html)

```
private function saveGame() : void {  
   var myFile:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("savegames/test.txt");  
   var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();  
   fs.open(myFile,FileMode.WRITE);  
   fs.writeUTFBytes("bytes To Write");  
   fs.close();  
}
```

Comment: can you give some links to tutorials about fileStream?

Answer (score -1):

I think the best solution is SQLite database as it's easy to use, evolve and change at any point when you will need to add data to that

- [SQLConnection docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/SQLConnection.html)
- [SQLite in Air 10 part tutorial](http://kirill-poletaev.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/working-with-sqlite-in-air-part-1.html)